# Singleton factory (base class) doesn't "clear" instance

Tags: c#, singleton

I have the following class to create a Singelton:

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    protected Singleton()
    { }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    private static T instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        { instance = SingletonCreator.Singleton; }

        return instance;
    }

    public static void ClearInstance()
    { instance = null; }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Inner classes

    private class SingletonCreator
    {
        #region Properties

        private static readonly T instance = typeof(T).InvokeMember(typeof(T).Name,
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) as T;

        internal static T Singleton
        { get { return instance; } }

        #endregion Properties
    }

    #endregion Inner classes
}
```

Then I've created a class 'Person' which is inheriting from this class, thus making it a Singleton.

```
public class Person : Singleton<Person>
{
    #region Constructors

    protected Person() { }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

And finally, I have my unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void then_the_new_instance_should_have_default_values_for_the_properties()
    {
        Person.GetInstance().Age = 1;
        Person.GetInstance().Name = "Unit";
        Person.GetInstance().Firstname = "Test";

        Person.ClearInstance();
        Assert.AreEqual(Person.GetInstance().Age, 0, "The age property of the requested instance is incorrect.");
        Assert.AreEqual(Person.GetInstance().Name, "", "The name property of the requested instance is incorrect.");
        Assert.AreEqual(Person.GetInstance().Firstname, "", "The firstname property of the requested instance is incorrect.");
    }
```

My guess is that the unit test should pass, because I asks an instance when the previous one is cleared.

But the person object has the same values as the object had before the ClearInstance() method.

I assumed that this was a safe implementation but it seems that I'm missing something here.

Someone have a clue?

Comment: B/w, why do you do `InvokeMember` to create instance rather than calling constructor directly?

Comment: That's because the class of which to create an instance cannot have a public constructor (voids Singleton pattern) and the logic to create a singleton and the class itself that needs to be a singleton can be in 2 different assemblies.

Comment: But aren't you inheriting from `Singleton<T>`?  Then you would have access to private constructor...

Comment: True, I guess I'm a bit lost here

Comment: The testing is irrelevant to the problem: it only shows the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that it looks like you have two levels in creating your singleton.  Your real singleton is actually the `SingletonCreator.instance`, and that one never gets cleared.

When `Singleton<T>` is creating an instance, it calls on `SingletonCreator.instance` to get the actual instance.  When you clear, you clear one from `Singleton<T>.instance`, but next time you create, it pulls existing one from `SingletonCreator.instance` which already has an instance that is returned to you.

I don't think you need the extra layer of `SingletonCreator`. Simply move that code to your `Singleton<T>` and that'll do it.

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    #region Constructors

    protected Singleton()
    { }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    private static readonly object instanceLock = new object();
    private static T instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock(instanceLock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = typeof(T).InvokeMember(typeof(T).Name,
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) as T; 
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public static void ClearInstance()
    { instance = null; }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

Comment: That's not a good approach, because the code "if (instance == null)" can be executed on 2 different threads at the same time and bot threads will create an instance which voids the Singleton Pattern. However, I do know right now why I have this behavior, next step is to solve it :-)

Comment: @Complexity Your original post doesn't provide MT-safety either.  So my answer does not consider MT issues as well.  Let me edit for MT...

Comment: Ok, I'll await it, I tought that it was thread safe, because the instance in the SingletonCreator is only created on creation of the class...

Comment: @Complexity ... and one more edit should simplify instanciation - I think it should work.

Comment: One issue with your updated answer, this.instancelock is not available because Singleton isn't a static class.

How about getting rid of the InvokedMember?

Comment: Ok, InvokeMember is gone right now, it's just the "this" keyword that doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Sorry, a couple of things doesn't work with your solution.
- The new() constraint in the Generic Singleton forces me to make a public constructor = voiding Singleton pattern.
- This is not working in this context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52545/discussion-between-lb2-and-complexity)